# Changing global variable value in if condition, then accessing the value in else

Tags: php, mysql, variables, scope, global-variables

I have a global variable being changed in if statement then accessed in else, but it does not have the same value and loses its value:

```
global $reqUserID;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        if (isset($_POST['viewReq'])) {

            $requests = new requests();
            $results = $requests->getRequest($_POST['reqID']);

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))

            $GLOBALS['reqUserID'] = $result['USER_ID']; //CORRECT VALUE HERE

        }
        else if (isset($_POST['approveBtn'])) {

            $var1 = $GLOBALS['reqUserID'];
            $sql = "SELECT EMAIL FROM user_info WHERE USER_ID='$var1'";//SOME OTHER VALUE HERE
            [...]
        }
```

Comment: **You will never be in the "if" and the "else" during the same code execution**. The code-paths are mutually exclusive. Check your program flow. (If the page is reloaded there will be a *new* `$GLOBALS`.)

Comment: for demonstration purposes i have edited the code here, there are no other syntax error in code

Comment: @jaminator, pst gives you exact answer about why your code does not work as you intented.

Comment: actually i am posting the page to itself so yes if and else can get executed

Comment: i guess the value is being lost in the post, i am gonna try a hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page was being posted to itself, and Global variable involved was not being posted to be used, so i made a hidden field filled it with the value of global variable on the first pass and posted the value and used it late using _POST array.

Answer (score 3):

If you set a value in the 'if' clause, then the 'else' clause will not be executed, and vice versa.  So, you could only get to the 'else' clause on a second iteration of the statement.  Then you need to understand where variables are defined, and when they become undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In one pass over the if-else construct you can either enter in the if-construct or the else construct. So, the change you make in if-part will not be visible in the code in else-if construct.

Comment: Would you be better off using the term 'statement' or 'clause' in place of 'loop'?